# How do I use Picasso Image Caching?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, caching, picasso

I need to access an image that has been cached after it has been transformed (or cropped) using Picasso.

What I am doing is taking a large image resource, cropping a screen-size piece of it out of it at run-time, and setting it to the background of a `RelativeLayout`.  So far I have used Picasso to accomplish this successfully.

Later in the app, I change the app layout by calling:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.OTHER_LAYOUT);
```

I would like to then access the cache where Picasso stored the cropped version of the image, and dynamically set the background of `OTHER_LAYOUT` to the stored version of the cropped image.

[This S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092656) seems relevant to accessing a bitmap cached by Picasso on device.

I am considering giving this solution a try.  But one user's comment (a comment on the accepted answer) makes me wonder if there is a better way.  Complicated solutions often seem more bug-prone.

"it seems can work. but in my opinion, it is not well offer. files are being saved somewhere. lib should give them to developers. it would be good instead of adding millions feature to picasso lib, adding very simple and essential features. I gave up to use picasso because of this. It has millions garbage features and very limited nice features."

Is there some way that Picasso allows me to access the image that was transformed and cached, and use it somewhere else (in a way that is simple & easy to use)?

If not, would another library give me greater convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think too much about reusing cached images, Picasso is very good at that and is well optimized for it. Just load the same URL / drawable and apply the transformation. If Picasso already cached it, it will be very fast, you can check if it is cached by `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` on Picasso instance.

Comment: I'm loading an image from the app resources and then transforming it.  Not downloading it.  How do I access the cached image after it has been transformed, for a different RelativeLayout ?

Comment: You need to load it again, Picasso will take it from the cache if present. After, you need to apply again the transformation. Picasso cache only the original image.